# Application of Mason theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $p,q,r$ coprime polynomials. **Show that $p^3-q^2=r^6$ violate [Mason-Stothers Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%E2%80%93Stothers_theorem).

My attempt:

We know we are in the condictions of the Mason's Theorem. Then, $\max\{3\deg p,2\deg r,6\deg d\}\leq N_0(p^3r^2d^6)−1$. Since $N_0(f)$ is the number of distinct roots of $f$, we will have that $N_0(p^3r^2d^6)=N_0(pr^2d^2)\leq\deg p+2\deg r+2\deg d$ and then

$$3\deg p+2\deg r+6\deg r\leq3\deg p+3\deg r+6\deg r−3⇒3≤degr.$$

Am I in the right path to find the contradiction?

Comment: Does $N_0$ mean the same thing as rad?  If not, what does it mean?  If so, why don't we have $N_0(p^3r^2d^6)=N_0(prd)?$

Comment: $N_0(f)$ means $\deg(rad(f))$, that is, the number of distinct roots of $f$. I edited one inequality.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're doing.  Are you trying to use the Mason-Struthers theorem to prove that there are no coprime polynomials $p,q,r$ such that $p^3-q^2=r^6?$

Comment: Yes, you're right! I tried to be more so I edited the original question. ($p,q$ and $r$ are coprime polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is easier than you are making it.  Let $P=\deg p, Q=\deg q, R= \deg r.$  Then we know $$\max(3P, 2Q, 6R) \le N_0(p^3q^2r^6)-1=N_0(pqr)-1 =P+Q+R-1\tag 1$$

Now suppose $\max(3P, 2Q, 6R)=3P.$ Then we have $$
\begin{align}
&2Q\le 3P \implies Q\le \frac{3P}{2}\\
&6R\le 3P \implies R \le \frac{P}{2}
\end{align}$$
and substituting into (1) gives $$3P<=P+\frac{3P}{2}+\frac{P}{2}-1=3P-1,$$
contradiction.  We deduce similar contradictions on assuming that the maximum is $2Q$ or $6R.$